# Facebook FB.getLoginStatus doesnt return in IE 7

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

General question: is FB JS API should work on IE7 perfect? Every call should return as in every other browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`FB.getLoginStatus`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) isn't supposed to return anything. You need to pass a callback function:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    // test response.status
});
```

The reason is that the Facebook JS SDK doesn't immediately know the status of the current user, because it doesn't have access to facebook cookies if it's running in your webpage.

The sdk should work on IE7.

Comment: answering my question: getLoginStatus freeze when using FB as page. U need to call FB.login first.